# Set multiple fields after selecting a document on the dialog list in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I use a dialog list field with a view for choices. I need not only to set the current field with a value of the selected document but multiple fields on the current form.

When I select a document I want to read some fields from the selected document and set values on the current mask. I try to set the document id in the current dialog list field and get it and read in some refresh action? Is this a good approach?

Thank you! Best regards, Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a button and `@PickList`. So I have full controll over the action.